# When to use Class.isInstance() & when to use instanceof operator?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java isInstance vs instanceOf operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140065/java-isinstance-vs-instanceof-operator)

When to use `Class.isInstance()` and when to use `instanceof` operator?

Java is providing two option for checking assignment compatibility. Which to use when?

Comment: If you are going to close a question as a duplicate, at least cite the earlier questions.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I think the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) gives you the answer to this one (albeit in a fairly nonspecific way):

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof
>   operator.

I take that to mean that `isInstance()` is primarily intended for use in code dealing with type reflection at runtime.  In particular, I would say that it exists to handle cases where you might not know in advance the type(s) of class(es) that you want to check for membership of in advance (rare though those cases probably are).

For instance, you can use it to write a method that checks to see if two arbitrarily typed objects are assignment-compatible, like:

```
public boolean areObjectsAssignable(Object left, Object right) {
    return left.getClass().isInstance(right);
}
```

In general, I'd say that using `instanceof` should be preferred whenever you know the kind of class you want to check against in advance.  In those very rare cases where you do not, use `isInstance()` instead.

Comment: Another typical use-case for the `isInstance` method is when dealing with generics. There are a lot of situations where you have the `Class<T>` object, and the only way to check whether an object belongs to that class is the `isInstance` method

Comment: When not to use `isInstance`  may also be helpful. e.g. I was trying to use `if (o.getClass().isInstance(Foo.class)) {...}` which didn't work. The subtly different `if (o.getClass().isInstance(new Foo)) {...}`  was what was needed.  Of course `if (o instaneOf Foo){...}` also worked, which is probably the correct solution when you are know the type(s).

Comment: @MikeT try: `MyObject.class.isInstance(Foo.class);` and see related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140145/3157899)

Comment: To see if two arbitrarily typed objects are assignment-compatible, there is [isAssignableFrom()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-). But I don't know if this was the case back in 2012.

Answer (score 81):

For `instanceof` you need to know the exact class at compile time.

```
if (foo instanceof ThisClassIKnowRightNow)
   ...
```

For `isInstance` the class is decided at run time.  (late binding)  e.g.

```
if (someObject.getClass().isInstance(foo))
   ...
```

Comment: +1: To the point.  Also with Java 8 streams, `.filter(ThisClassIKnowRightNow.class::isInstance)` is slightly more concise than `.filter(o -> o instanceof ThisClassIKnowRightNow)`.

Comment: Suppose in a multi-catch example, I have an example like `try{}catch(A | B | C ex){//here I want to know what type (A/B/C) of exception occurs at runtime. How would we use your approach here?}`