# How to access different attributes of different implementation of the same interface

Tags: java, list, interface, implements, mixed-type

I have an interface

```
public interface Inter {
    int interAttr = 0;   
}
```

And two classes that implements it, each one with an additional attribute and each one of different type.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Impl1 implements Inter {
    public int impl1Attr;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public class Impl2 implements Inter {
    public String impl2Attr;
}
```

And I have list of `Inter` objects that are a mix of `Impl1` and `Impl2`

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Impl1 i11 = new Impl1(0);
        Impl1 i12 = new Impl1(1);
        Impl2 i21 = new Impl2("zero");
        Impl2 i22 = new Impl2("one");
        List<inter> implList = new ArrayList<Inter>();
        implList.add(i11);
        implList.add(i12);
        implList.add(i21);
        implList.add(i22);
        for (Inter el : implList){
            // this of course works
            int a = el.interAttr1;
            // But how do I get access to impl1Attr and impl2Attr?
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I can query `i11.impl1Attr` or `impl21.impl2Attr` in the body of the `main`
But is there a way for me to have access to the attributes of the different implementations in the list in the `for` loop?

Comment: I'd say - no, there is no easy way, what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: If you wanted to access each individual class' specific attribute, then I suggest avoid putting them in a list which takes the interface as a type. The list is catering for objects implementing the interface, not their class specific attributes.

Comment: @TM00 this is just a very simplified example from a much larger project. Cannot change data structure very easily.

Comment: @IlyaBursov I am writing some input validation for an optimization routine. It happens that the input class contains a mixture of two different implementations of the same interface, in a list.

Comment: @JacoSolari if object can be validated, then interface should have method validate, then each object will implement it and your loop just call this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably oversimplifying the problem, but is [`instanceof`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instanceof) + casting not an option?

```
for (Inter el : implList) {

    int a = el.interAttr;

    if (el instanceof Impl1)
        System.out.println(((Impl1)el).impl1Attr);

    if (el instanceof Impl2)
        System.out.println(((Impl2)el).impl2Attr);
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted and it works. I have tried `el.getClass().isInstance( Impl1.class )` but was not working. Do you maybe know the difference between your approach and this one?

Comment: I did not before now, but here is a great answer to that exact question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692214/when-to-use-class-isinstance-when-to-use-instanceof-operator